# How do you log out of Stack Overflow using the 2017 top bar?

Tags: support, user-interface, top-bar

Since the top bar navigation update, I have not been able to find a log out / log off button or link anywhere. I'm certain there used to be one that appeared when moving the mouse pointer over the Stack Overflow logo, which is now no longer there.

I'll put in the feature request tag, but I really shouldn't need to request such a feature be added, when it should already exist for the security of a user's account.

Comment: i don't recall any Stack Exchange Site logo having any sort of hover effect. the log out button to me has always been in the menu you got when you clicked the Stack Exchange logo to the top left, in the current nav bar is on the opposite site (the Stack Exchange Icon)

Comment: OK, so it may not have been a hover effect, but none-the-less, I can't see a way of logging out. Currently, clicking on the logo just sends me back to the home page of the site.

Comment: @yellowantphil Thanks for that, so they have moved it. It seems I skipped over it when I moved the mouse pointer over the icon, and it said "A list of all 166 Stack Exchange sites", which I wasn't interested in viewing at the time. Maybe they should update the title to include a mention of a log out feature.

Comment: Yeah, so as far as I know, 'Title' attribute in HTML is supposed to convey what a link is for, when it is not otherwise clear to the user. Since I don't use stackoverflow that often, I didn't recognise the icon in conjunction with its usual feature set. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is on the top right corner of Stack Exchange icon

[image]